# Rails multiple select box for different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, html-select

I have a class User, which has many Events and belongs to many Groups. I want to allow user to create Event and restrict who he wants the invite by Group, by user id or by both.

How should I allow for multiple select box tag that shows both groups and individuals as selectable? I am thinking of creating something like acts_as, but it seems to be unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WARNING!!! First Iteration solution - it could be simpler

You might need a polymorphic relation to achieve the mapping.

```
Event
  has_many :invitations
  has_many :user_invitations, :class_name => "Invitation", :conditions => "inviteable_type = 'User'"
  has_many :group_invitations, :class_name => "Invitation", :conditions => "inviteable_type = 'Group'"


Invitation
  belongs_to :inviteable, :polymorphic => true
  #Invitations table would have inviteable_id, inviteable_type columns
User
  has_many :invitations, :as => :inviteable
Group
  has_many :invitations, :as => :inviteable
```

Now you can have
`Event.first.inviteables (this will return a collection of Users and Groups)

In your view, name the options for your 2 collections differently, example:

```
<select name='event[event_inviteables]' ...>
<option value='group[][1]'>Group 1</option>
..
<option value='user[][1]'>User 1</option>
```

In your Event model, you'll need to have an `event_inviteables=` method to determine which ones are users, and which ones are groups and update the inviteable collections accordingly

```
Event
  def event_inviteables=(*args)
    user_ids = #some magic to extract user_ids from args
    group_ids = #some magic to extract group_ids from args
    self.user_invitation_ids = user_ids
    self.group_invitation_ids = group_ids
  end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed answer. I got the first part right (polymorphic association) and I can call Event.first.invitables. However, I can't implement the second part, namely, the check box tag. (I am sorry for confusing selection box with check_box).  As you know very well, for check_box_tag, I need to pass an array [id, class_name] instead of just id: invitable => {{id => "1", name => "User"}, {id => "4", name => "Group"}}. How should I adept your solution for check box tag? Thanks again.

Comment: Check box tag takes name and value only `<%= check_box_tag 'event[event_inviteables][user][]', user.id %><%= check_box_tag 'event[event_inviteables][group][]', group.id %>` (of course you need also to test if the user should be checked or not in event edit page).